# save image stream to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, png

In my Laravel controller I'm attempting to take a string of png image data, then save it as a `png` to storage using `put`:

```
$image_string = $request->get('image_string', false);
$filename = 'temp_image';

if ($image_string) {
    $resource = imagecreatefromstring($image_string);
    Log::debug("Storing image");
    if ($resource !== false) {
        Storage::put('public/' . $filename . '.png', imagepng($resource));
    } else {
        Log::error("Failed to get resource from string");
    }
}
```

If I break out just the `imagecreatefromstring($image_string)` and `imagepng($resource)` parts, the file is created as expected. But somewhere in the `Storage::put` the image is either corrupted or lost, because while an image with the right filename and extension exists, it has no data and appears as a black box when viewed.

Is there a different way I need to handle the image store routine?

Comment: Try `Storage::putFileAs('public', imagepng($resource), $filename.'.png');`

Comment: @sykez that throw an error: `Call to a member function getRealPath() on boolean` in `laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php`

Comment: Aah, I guess it's because it's not an File instance. Perhaps you can provide the code for `imagepng()` and `imagecreatefromstring()`. Either way, as Stefano mentioned, you should use Intervention to handle all image related functions instead. Especially if it involves converting format and resizes. Also if you're handling an image upload, you should just use `Storage::putFile('public', $request->image);`

Comment: @sykez `imagepng` and `imagecreatefromstring` are in the PHP (with php-gd) -- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stefano Cortese and @sykez-- the solution was a blend of both ideas.

```
$image_string = $request->get('image_string', false);
$filename = 'temp_image';

if ($image_string) {
    $resource = Image::make($image_string)->encode('png');
    Log::debug("Storing image");
    if ($resource !== false) {
        Storage::put("public/{$filename}.png", (string) $resource);
    } else {
       Log::error("Failed to get resource from string");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you can not change the image extension for every type of images in this way.

Check this PHP image manipulation library: http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction

You can easily integrate it in Laravel and there is an API to convert images in different formats: http://image.intervention.io/api/encode